# Wordpress - Visual Editor Broken

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm having a real nightmare trying to debug an issue on a Wordpress Woocommerce website. At some point the Visual Editor tab on the classic editor on both pages and Woocommerce Products has stopped working. I've tried all the obvious fixes including the following:

- Deactivating all plugins and switching to Twenty Twenty Theme
- Checking profile setting 'disable visual editor' is unchecked (have also tried checking/unchecking)
- Adding the line define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); to wp-config
- Reuploading the tinymce folder to the wp-includes/js directory
- Reinstalling Wordpress
- Installing the Advanced Tiny MCE plugin

In the browser console it shows the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
post.php?post=23835&action=edit:2429 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCEPreInit is not defined
    at post.php?post=23835&action=edit:2429
    at post.php?post=23835&action=edit:2437
2post.php?post=23835&action=edit:2392 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCEPreInit is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.initialize (post.php?post=23835&action=edit:2392)
8editor.min.js?ver=5.8.2:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mceInit')
    at n (editor.min.js?ver=5.8.2:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (editor.min.js?ver=5.8.2:2)
    at C (tinymce.min.js?ver=49110-20201110:2)
    at HTMLDocument.d (tinymce.min.js?ver=49110-20201110:2)
```

Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm _ I'm not sure this advice will help but perhaps it's worth looking into: Although I wasn't using TinyMCE plugin I went through pretty much what you've described and even though I carried out a complete WP re-install the problem persisted _ Afterwards I found out that the database used by WP still contained data from the previous install which had not been deleted in the WP re-install _ It might be helpful to investigate whether this is the case in your situation, in which case you would need to reset the database _ Good Luck!

Comment: I should add that the extra data I found in my database was left there by the plugin, which didn't clean up everything when it was uninstalled. The only way to remove it completely was to reset the database prior to re-installing WordPress. Once I had done all this the problem disappeared